# how can i SELECT FROM sqlite3_table WHERE column_name IN variable tuple?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, select, where-clause

I have this tuple:

```
topics = ('sport', 'math', 'science', 'literature')
```

This `topics` tuple changes for every user (his length also changes)

How can I select from a sqlite3 table only the rows where their `topic` column's value equals to one of the topics tuple's values?

I tried to use this command but it didn't work:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('questions_stack.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM questions WHERE topic IN ?""", subject_tuple)
```

Can I select from the table like that if the `topics` tuple's length changes every time and is not constant?

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: both the values and the length of the tuple changes for each user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count how many values there are in the list, and generate the corresponding placeholders.

Something like:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('questions_stack.db')
c = conn.cursor()
binds = ",".join("?" * len(subject_tuple))
sql = '''select * from questions where topic in ({})'''.format(binds)
cur.execute(sql, subject_tuple)
```